# Как читать значения из текстового файла в массив?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как читать значения из текстового файла в массив?

Comment: в консольном приложении как чтобы значения представить в массив динамич список и типизированный файл...что это значит

Answer (score 1):

Сложно понять, что имелось в виду. Считать в очередь (список) можно, например, так

```
ifstream in;
deque<string> out;

in.open(filename);
if (in.is_open()) {
{
    while (in) {
        string s;
        getline(in, s);
        out.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: а в массив как считать??

Comment: точно также, только вместо deque объявить достаточно большой a[]